# How to publish and precompile projects that used GleamTech FileUltimate in?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I used GleamTech FileUltimate file management component in my project.
I add this assembly to each page that I want to use FileUltimate:

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="GleamTech" Assembly="GleamTech.FileUltimate" Namespace="GleamTech.FileUltimate" %>
```

Or Add this to web.config file :

```
<httpModules>
   <add name="FileUploaderModule" type="GleamTech.Web.UploadModule"/>
</httpModules>

<pages>
  <controls>
    <add tagPrefix="GleamTech" assembly="GleamTech.FileUltimate" namespace="GleamTech.FileUltimate"/>
  </controls>
</pages>
```

When I want to build and run website, give me a message that :

**there were build errors. would you like to continue and run the last successful build.**

I choose yes in this case and website works correctly, But when I want to publish website and choose precompile in the last step, compiler give some error:

**Error: Cannot create an object of type 'GleamTech.FileSystems.Location' from its string representation '~/upload/fm/' for the 'Location' property.**

**Error: Literal content ('') is not allowed within a 'System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection`1[[GleamTech.FileUltimate.FileManagerRootFolder, GleamTech.FileUltimate, Version=4.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=a05198837413a6d8]]'.**

**Error:    System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection`1[[GleamTech.FileUltimate.FileManagerRootFolder, GleamTech.FileUltimate, Version=4.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=a05198837413a6d8]] must have items of type 'GleamTech.FileUltimate.FileManagerRootFolder'. 'GleamTech:FileManagerAccessControl' is of type 'GleamTech.FileUltimate.FileManagerAccessControl'.**

Is there any way to precompile my project and ignore these errors?
How can I solve my problem?

Best regards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For future reference,

This issue is fixed in FileUltimate v5.3.8. The problem was only with “Web Site” projects and not “Web Application” projects.

> Fixed: In Web Site projects, when you added FileManager markup in an aspx page and built the web site, the build failed with the following error message (actually 3 error messages but main one is this, others are consequences): Cannot create an object of type 'GleamTech.FileSystems.Location' from its string representation.

Actually there was a workaround for older versions:

1. Include only this markup in aspx page:

   ```xml
   <GleamTech:FileManager ID="fileManager" runat="server" 
                      Width="800"
                      Height="600" 
                      Resizable="True" />
   ```
2. Then in the codebehind aspx.cs file, add your root folders and access controls:

   ```cs
   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       var rootFolder = new FileManagerRootFolder
       {
           Name = "A Root Folder",
           Location = "~/App_Data/RootFolder1"
       };

       rootFolder.AccessControls.Add(new FileManagerAccessControl
       {
           Path = @"\",
           AllowedPermissions = FileManagerPermissions.Full
       });

       fileManager.RootFolders.Add(rootFolder);
   }
   ```